# Trouble loading fiona

Tags: fiona, dll

I'm having trouble loading fiona. I am able to import/run GDAL and GeoPandas with no issues but when I try loading fiona, I get an error message (please see below). I have python (3.9.11) through ArcGIS Pro and installed fiona (1.9.1), gdal (3.6.2) using the "add packages" from the ArcGIS Pro package manager. My ArcGIS Pro runs on the Windows 64-bit operating system. Is there a way to troubleshoot this using the ArcGIS Pro package manager?

I need this package for my work but I don't have administration rights to do an easy fix if the system corrupts, when troubleshooting using the command prompts.

```
#import package
from osgeo import gdal    
import geopandas as gpd    
import fiona

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [25]:
Line 4:     import fiona

File C:\Users\jjin\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-clone-6\lib\site-packages\fiona\__init__.py, in <module>:
Line 86:    from fiona._env import (

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _env: The specified module could not be found.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Install an [older version of fiona](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/359070/2856).

You don't say what version of ArcGIS Pro, but given your python and gdal versions, you're probably running Pro 3.x.  I've got 2.9 so can't tell you which fiona version to install, but 1.8.4 works for me in Pro 2.9.

[image]

Comment: I have ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0 and I assume I only have fiona available in the following versions (1.9.1 / 1.8.22 / 1.8.21). I wonder if there's a specific order I should follow when installing fiona. Like, was I supposed to install fiona before or after another package??

Comment: I don't know, I just cloned my arcgispro-py3 env and installed fiona into the clone straight afterward.